# How to add Smooth Scroll in MuPDF?

Tags: android, mupdf

I am using muPDF to display PDFs in my app...
I figured out how to do Vertical Scroll from Horizontal but it isn't smooth scrolling...
it is more like pulling, how to add Continue Scrolling or Smooth scroll like Google pdf reader?

Comment: I have the same issue , did you find the answer

Comment: @MinaFawzy Yepp, I found this Great Repo - https://github.com/archko/Mupdf :)